# Make Home and End Keys Move Window in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 12.0. When I click on text on a page, I get a blinking cursor. When I press <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd>, it goes to the start or end of the line.

I want those keys to move the window to the start or end of the page. That's the normal behavior, or used to be, right? I don't know what configuration setting I changed to make it behave like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two operation modes with cursor keys in Firefox.  One is navigate in pages with cursor keys, and the other is not.

If you have `Navigate with Cursor Keys` enabled in `Options / Advanced / General / Accessibility`, then the navigation behaves like a text editor, and <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> go to the beginning and end of line.  If you have this disabled, then <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> go to the beginning and end of the page.